# Capture messages from protected websocket with puppeteer

Tags: websocket, service, puppeteer, service-worker

I simply cannot just capture the websocket messages with puppeteer when the websocket is marked with a gear icon in the developer tools.
The chrome or the puppeteer dev tools can show the messages on these kind of websockets but I cannot subscribe to got them from js.

```
const client = await page.target().createCDPSession()

await client.send('Network.enable')

client.on('Network.webSocketFrameReceived', ({requestId, timestamp, response}) => {
  console.log('Network.webSocketFrameReceived', requestId, timestamp, response.payloadData)
})
```

The received callback never will be called.

What does this gear icon mean?

Do you have a workaround or solution to capture the messages in js?

Thanks for your help